# How to caffeinate a function on CLI?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

Mac's `caffeinate` tool accepts the name of a utility: `caffeinate sleep 1`, for instance.  Is there any way for it to accept a function as well?  For example:

```
function mysleep {
  sleep 2
}

caffeinate mysleep    # mysleep: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

`caffeinate` launches executables. However, shell functions exist only within the shell. Shell functions are not executables.

#### Workaround: call bash directly

This works best for one-liners and simple commands.

```
caffeinate bash -c 'sleep 2'
```

Multi-liners work too:

```
caffeinate bash <<EOF
  sleep 2
  echo "done :D"
EOF
```

You can use functions:

```
caffeinate bash <<EOF
  function mysleep {
    sleep 2
  }
  mysleep
EOF
```

#### Workaround: call a script instead of a function

Instead of doing your work inside a function, split it out into a separate script:

```
caffeinate mysleep.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# mysleep.sh
sleep 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/caffeinate.html):

`caffeinate -- prevent the system from sleeping on behalf of a utility`

A function is not a utility as a utility will have a process ID (pid) associated with it.  When you specify a utility, `caffeinate` forks a process and holds an assertion that prevents sleep until that process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

`caffeinate` requires that there be an object to run, a function does not fill this requirement.

Change your function into a shell script and it will work fine. So for your example:

```
`#!/bin/bash 
sleep 2
```

saved into a file called `mysleep` and then `caffeinate mysleep` will work fine (so long as the file `mysleep` is in your system PATH.).

`